# Timer is not working in separate class in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I would like to get the time my user instance is alive.
Therefore I added the following timer function.
But it does not work nevermind what I try:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

public MainWindow() {
    User myUser = new User();

    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimerElapsed);
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Enabled = true;

    myUser.setTimer(timer);
}

private void OnTimerElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    User currentUser = (User)source;
    MessageBox.Show("OnTimerElapsed: " + currentUser.Id);
}
```

This is my UserClass which includes the timer instance:

```
public class User : NotifyPropertyChanged {

    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;

    public void setTimer(System.Timers.Timer timer)
    {
        _timer = timer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you have a local variable of type User declared in MainWindow. This variables goes out of scope when the constructor terminates. What happen to the timer inside that variable? I bet is destroyed with the variable itself. Move the User variable at the class global scope and tell me if it works now.

Comment: Are you calling `_timer.Start()` anywhere? I don't see it.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.start(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @PaulGriffin, as noted in the comments on one of the answers, setting `Enabled` to `true` is equivalent to calling `Start()`.

Comment: Nevermind, I see how that works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Timer` is good for causing actions to happen after some interval, or on a periodic basis. But a `Timer` does not in and of itself actually keep track of time. You need a `Stopwatch` for that.

Something that might work in your example:

```
class User
{
    private Stopwatch _alive = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    public TimeSpan Alive { get { return _alive.Elapsed; } }
}
```

This adds a `Stopwatch` to your `User` object so that it knows how long it's been alive.

Then in your window code:

```
public MainWindow() {
    User myUser = new User();

    myUser.Timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    myUser.Timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => OnTimerElapsed(myUser);
    myUser.Timer.AutoReset = true;
    myUser.Timer.Enabled = true;
}

private void OnTimerElapsed(User currentUser) {
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("OnTimerElapsed: {0}, alive {1:0} seconds",
        currentUser.Id, currentUser.Alive.TotalSeconds));
}
```

This does a couple of things:

- It changes the timer handler so that it captures and passes the `myUser` object reference to the actual handler method. In your example, you were trying to cast the `source` parameter, but that's the `Timer` object, not a `User` object.
- It retrieves the `TimeSpan` value from the `Alive` property, and displays the value as seconds.

Note that the `User` object does not itself need to know anything about the `Timer` object, at least not to accomplish the above.

Something like that should work; obviously you will make modifications according to your specific need.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast the `object source` in the `OnTimerElapsed` to a type `User`

It's a `Timer` type.

You are causing an `System.InvalidCastException` every time the Timer ticks.
It's not crashing, because it's on a worker thread.

By the way, simply setting a breakpoint on the line

`User currentUser = (User)source;`

would have revealed this error.

The handler method's first parameter is always the object that fired the event, in this case, it's the Timer instance, not the `User` type defined by you.